# Problems installing Web version of Agora.io

Tags: agora.io

My server is linux centos...

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video/tree/master/Web/17-Multistream

**How much I give the cmneto:**
npm install

**A lot of alerts appear and finally, this error:**
husky > Setting up git hooks
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
husky > Failed to install

Comment: Hey, husky is post-install tool. It is looking for a git repository but it can't find one. Can you try cloning the repository using the CLI instead of downloading it from GitHub using the UI?

Comment: Hello,

I didn't quite understand what you said. But do you do freelance work? If so, and you have already worked with Agora.io, I would like to hire you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. `git clone https://github.com/AgoraIO/Advanced-Video.git` to download the repository to your server
2. `cd ./Web/17-Multistream/` to navigate inside the project.
3. `npm install` to install the dependencies.

Your error is basically saying that the `.git` folder is not present inside your directory. It won't be downloaded when you download it from the GitHub UI.

This usually won't cause any issues but the project is using [husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky). This causes an error since husky can't work without a `.git` folder